# UIDatePicker bumps day/time when rendered

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I am adding a UIDatePicker to my app, and I am using a UITextField.inputView to render it, instead of a regular keyboard (so we would not take additional space for the picker on a view).

I use `.wheels` as a style for the datePicker.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var field: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        field.delegate = self
    }
}
extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == field {
            let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
            datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateTime // or .time, or .date
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
            field.inputView = datePicker
        }
    }
}
```

When testing this code on Simulator of IPhone SE (2nd), there is an issue with selecting dates: when I try to select any date, it bumps the first component by 3 elements into the future:

- if `datePickerMode` is `.dateTime`, it bumps by 3 days,
- if `datePickerMode` is `.date`, it bumps by 3 months,
- if `datePickerMode` is `.time`, it bumps by 3 hours.

Besides, any taps in the `ViewController` trigger this date bumping behaviour.

I created a simple repro project: https://github.com/egorshulga/datepicker-debugging.   There I added another UIDatePicker, placed it just below text field, to show that for regular pickers the issue *is not reproducible*.

Here is screen capture with the issue demonstration:
[demo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF5Kt.gif)
[demo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFezP.gif)

My environment:

- macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
- UTC+3
- Xcode 12.4 (12D4e)
- failing simulator: IPhone SE 2nd gen (iOS 14.4)

What I tried (and did not work):

- wrapping UIDatePicker into a View as a subview
- calling `datePicker.sizeToFit()` before assigning it as `field.inputView`
- changing to other timezones on host mac

Besides, I checked the issue in other simulators (IPhone 12 Pro Max, IPhone 8) and on a real IPhone 11 Pro Max - the issue *is not reproducible*. Unfortunately, I don't have IPhone SE 2nd gen as a real device to check this behaviour.

What could be wrong with IPhone SE 2nd gen simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, as far as I can see, the issue is no longer reproducible on IPhone SE 2nd Gen simulator iOs 14.5 (latest Xcode version 12.5 12E262 arrived on April 26 2021). Thanks, Apple!